# Flask app executes in the command line but doesn't run in the browser

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, cmd

I have a simple Flask app that checks if the username requirements are met or not.
Here's the script:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index4.html')

@app.route('/report')
def report():
    lower_letter = False
    upper_letter = False
    num_end = False
    username = request.args.get('username')
    lower_letter = any(c.islower() for c in username)
    lower_letter = any(c.isupper() for c in username)
    num_end= username[-1].isdigit()
    report = lower_letter and upper_letter and num_end
    return render_template('report.html', report=report,upper = upper_letter, lower= lower_letter,num_end = num_end)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

The other files(HTML) are structured (in template directory) like this:

```
/python programs
   07-Simple-Project.py
   /templates
      index4.html
      report.html
```

The problem is when I execute it in command like using:

```
python 07-Simple-Project.py
```

It executes the script without giving any error but doesn't opens it in the browser! Solutions of other such problems mention the absence of app.run() , "****name****" etc. But I can't find any error here! This behavior is very random, sometimes my app runs without any anomaly but other times..this happens!
[image: It simply executes without giving any link to server or any error!]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Works for me. You should access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Comment: But it shows _**http://127.0.0.1:5000/** refused to connect!!_

Comment: Sometimes  it shows _**This site can’t be reached**_